# Mapping JAXB data to a Domain Model

Tags: xml, mapping, jaxb

I get an InputStream from a web services call, and I use JAXB to convert it to objects, so I do not have to parse the xml.

The objects contain a bunch of data I am not interested in, and of the data I care about, I want to instantiate a custom domain model type object.
For instance, the JAXB objects contain about 50 pieces of data spread over maybe 20 classes.
I want to pick the data I care about, around 10 pieces of data, and instantiate my domain model class with the 10 pieces of data.

I have to use Java 1.4, is there a framework I can use, or should I just iterate over the JAXB objects and get the data I care about then instantiate a domain model and set the data?

Comment: Are you using a JAXB 1 impl with JDK 1.4?

Comment: how can i tell which JAXB version i'm using?

Comment: found it, using JAXB 1.3

Comment: is this something to consider: [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using JAXB 1.0**

You could apply an XSLT transform to the document to just the information you care about.  Then you could create an XML schema for this smaller document and generate your object model from it.  My answer below to a related question will give you a feel of how the javax.xml.transform APIs fit in:

- [How to get jaxb to Ignore certain data during unmarshalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112404/how-to-get-jaxb-to-ignore-certain-data-during-unmarshalling/5118189#5118189)

**Using JAXB 2.0**

If you are able to upgrade to Java SE 5, then you can leverage JAXB 2.0.  I lead the [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) implementation, and you may be interested in our XPath extension:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html

Comment: very interesting idea, i think i'll look into the transform idea since i cannot upgrade at this time

Answer (score 0):

Writing some custom XPath queries to pluck out the fields you want would be fairly clean and simple. You can get XPath as part of xalan or a bunch of other xml libraries I believe: [API Link](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/apidocs/org/apache/xpath/XPathAPI.html)

To clarify (if you haven't used XPath before), XPath allows you to write a simple, pathed query to search through an xml document. So `root/child/grandchild/` would return the value of the grandchild node, which was underneath the child node, which was underneath the root node.