# "Unrecognized field (..), not marked as ignorable" while jaxb unmarshalling xml input

Tags: spring, jaxb, unmarshalling, resttemplate

in a typical Spring MVC project, I am trying to access objects that are fetched from an external webservice source. The actual integration of this data wasn't actually - until now - my part within the project. But it's broke and I'll have to fix it. That is to say: I am not perfectly familar with the related code.

## Backgrounds

### The Data

The XML Data, which is received from the external web service looks like this:

```
<offeredServiceTOes>
   <OfferedService deleted="false">
      <id>0001_01-u001/igd</id>
      <title>Umschlagleistung (001)</title>
      <mainType>turnover</mainType>
      <services>
         <service id="tos5yyeivg">
            <title>Umschlag Bahn - Binnenschiff</title>
            <mainType>turnover</mainType>
            <systemId>RailRiver</systemId>
            <meansOfTransport id="motRail">
               <title>Bahn</title>
               <description>Bahn</description>
               <systemId>Rail</systemId>
            </meansOfTransport>
            <meansOfTransportRel id="motRiver">
               <title>Binnenschiff</title>
               <description>Binnenschiff</description>
               <systemId>River</systemId>
            </meansOfTransportRel>
         </service>
         <service id="tos5yyeiw0">
            [...]
         </service>
         [...]
      </services>
      [...]
    </OfferedService>
    [...]
<offeredServiceTOes>
```

### The Unmarshalling

- The Method using Spring Rest Templates looks like this:

  ```
  @Override
  public List<OfferedServiceTO> getOfferedServices() {
      return restTemplate.getForObject(
              dataServiceUriTemplate, 
              OfferedServiceTOList.class,
              OFFERED_SERVICES
      );
  ```
- The related `OfferedServiceTOList` class:

  ```
  @XmlRootElement(name="OfferedService")
  public class OfferedServiceTO
  {

      @XmlElement
      @XmlID
      public String id;

      // [...]

      @XmlElementWrapper(name="services")
      @XmlElement(name="service")
      public List<ServiceTO> services; 

      // [...]
  }
  ```
- The related `ServiceTO` Class

  ```
  @XmlRootElement(name="service")
  public class ServiceTO
  {
      // [...]
      @XmlElement
      public String title;

      /[...]
      @XmlElementWrapper(name="mainServices")
      @XmlElement(name="service")
      public List<ServiceTO> mainServices;
  }
  ```
- The marshaller/unmarshaller xml bean configuration

  ```
  <bean id="jaxbMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
      <property name="classesToBeBound">
          <list>
              <value>a.b.beans.ServiceTO</value>
              <value>a.b.OfferedServiceTO</value>
              [...]
          </list>
      </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="xmlMessageConverter"
      class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
      <constructor-arg ref="jaxbMarshaller" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="jsonHttpMessageConverter"
      class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
      <property name="objectMapper" ref="jaxbJacksonObjectMapper"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="jaxbJacksonObjectMapper"
      class="a.b.path.to.extended.jaxb.JaxbJacksonObjectMapper">
  </bean>

  <bean id="jsonView" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
      <property name="objectMapper" ref="jaxbJacksonObjectMapper" />
  </bean>
  ```
- And finally, the above mentioned `path.to.extended.jaxb.JaxbJacksonObjectMapper`is:

  ```
      public class JaxbJacksonObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

          public JaxbJacksonObjectMapper() {
              final AnnotationIntrospector primary = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector();
              final AnnotationIntrospector secondary = new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector();
              AnnotationIntrospector introspector = new AnnotationIntrospector.Pair(primary, secondary);
              DeserializationConfig deserializationConfig = super.getDeserializationConfig().withAnnotationIntrospector(introspector);
              DeserializationProblemHandler errorHandler = new DeserializationProblemHandler() {
                  @Override
                  public boolean handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext ctxt, JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer, Object beanOrClass,
                          String propertyName) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
                      //TODO Logging (unbekanntes Input-JSON)
                      ctxt.getParser().skipChildren();
                      return true;
                  }
              };
              deserializationConfig.addHandler(errorHandler );
              super.setDeserializationConfig(deserializationConfig);
              SerializationConfig serializationConfig = super.getSerializationConfig().withAnnotationIntrospector(introspector);
              serializationConfig.set(Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
              super.setSerializationConfig(serializationConfig);
          }

      }
  ```

## The Problem

The problem is, that the Annotations of the first listing, `@XmlElementWrapper(name="services") @XmlElement(name="service")`, look fine to me regarding the xml data wrapping. But I keep getting the error:

```
[...] nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: Unrecognized field "service" (Class a.b.ServiceTO), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@76d697d9; line: 7, column: 18] (through reference chain: a.b.OfferedServiceTO["services"]->a.b.ServiceTO["service"]); nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "service" (Class a.b.ServiceTO), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@76d697d9; line: 7, column: 18] (through reference chain: a.b.OfferedServiceTO["services"]->a.b.ServiceTO["service"])
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
```

Similar related questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325362/jaxb-unmarshalling-multiple-xml-elements-into-single-class) were fixed by annotating `@XmlElementWrapper(name="services")`. But this is already present.

I would appreciate any suggestions. Thank you.

-- Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this was easier than expected. The List field needs a wrapping layer. A closer look to the json document revealed the solution:

In `OfferedServiceTO.class` the

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="services")
@XmlElement(name="service")
public List<ServiceTO> services;
```

has to be changed to

```
@XmlElement(name="services")
public ServiceTOList services;
```

where `ServiceTOList.class` has to be something like:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="service")
public class ServiceTOList extends ArrayList<ServiceTO> {

    public List<ServiceTO> services;
}
```