# RestFul Service (spring3) CLIENT java?

Tags: java, xml, json, spring

I am trying to unmarshal JAXB in client side, but I am getting **Object's properties NULL.**

Thats what I am doing to unmarshal

```
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:9191/service/firstName/tony?format=xml");   

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/atom+xml");

    if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + conn.getResponseCode());
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        (conn.getInputStream())));


    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(LDAPUsers.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();


    LDAPUsers lu =  (LDAPUsers) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(br);
    ArrayList<LDAPUser> list = new ArrayList<LDAPUser>();


    //list.addAll(lu.getCounty());
    **System.out.println(lu.ldapUser.get(0).getFirstName());//this is giving NULL**

    conn.disconnect();
```

Pls Help !!!

Comment: debug and use a break point into the list, check that this list is not empty and objects had all properties set.

Comment: It does not hit the setter...

Comment: What do your XML and domain objects look like?

Answer (score 0):

Check that your class is serialized correctly and annotated with **@XmlRootElement** and **@XmlElement**.

Check [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325362/jaxb-unmarshalling-multiple-xml-elements-into-single-class) and this [other one](http://loianegroner.com/2011/06/jaxb-custom-binding-java-util-date-spring-3-serialization/). Another [full example](http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-30-rest-example).

Put some assertions to check **not null** objects and **list not empty**.

Finally if you are using spring 3 I don't understand why you are managing connections and input streams... Try an approach using controller, maybe you need a custom unmarshaller:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/myurl")
public ModelAndView getUsers(@RequestBody List<LDAPUsers> users) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set an instance of `ValidationEventhandler` on the `Unmarshaller` to be notified of any problems that occur during the unmarshal process.  This can help in debugging the problem:

```java
    jaxbUnmarshaller.setEventHandler(new ValidationEventHandler() {

        @Override
        public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
            System.out.println(event.getMessage());
            return true;
        }

    });
```

**Client Example**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-55.html